# locust task method can't get the global value when "on_test_start" exist

Tags: global-variables, locust

I have a task in locust script,before the task running with hundreds users,I wangt another operation can change the var "user_var", so that   "user_var"'s  new value can be used when the task running.

but unfortunately, when i'm  running  the script, the result is different。
"user_var" in on_test_start has been changed, in the task,its value is still zero.

I print the var id，it's different.   so  what happened,can somebody tell me?  thanks

[image]

code as follow

```
base_url="http://baidu.com"
user_var = 0
print("init  var id：{}".format(id(user_var)))


@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(environment,**kwargs):
    global  user_var
    user_var = 1
    print("method  var id：{}".format(id(user_var)))
    print("user_var：{}".format(user_var))


class MyService(HttpUser):
    wait_time=between(1,2)
    @task()
    def points_acquire(self):
        print("class var id：{}".format(id(user_var)))
        print("user_var：{}".format(user_var))


if __name__=='__main__':
    run_script=os.path.basename(__file__)
    master_cmd='start locust -f {} --host={} --master '.format(run_script,base_url)
    worker_cmd=' && start locust -f {}  --worker'.format(run_script)
    total_cmd=master_cmd+worker_cmd*1
    os.system(total_cmd)
```

Comment: events.test_start used to not fire on master. It was fixed, maybe in 2.0 or some other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per definiton of the event:

> """
> Fired when a new load test is started. It's not fired again if the number of
> users change during a test. When running locust distributed the event is only fired
> on the master node and not on each worker node.
> """

https://docs.locust.io/en/1.4.0/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop

So you are initiating variable as 0 and the event doesnt fire in worker nodes so it stays 0,in master node the event fires and changes the value.

Edit: It seems the logic behind this has changed since last I checked it might work if you update your locust version

Comment: I got the expected result after upgrading the version to  2.2.1.